# How do you unregister a table from a esri geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, postgresql, esri-geodatabase

How do you reverse the "Register with Geodatabase" operation?

I reckon it isn't uncommon to accidentally register (since it is the first option on Manage menu in ArcCatalog 10.2).

Is there a tool (or python function) that can reverse this?

Comment: The only safe way is to delete the table (using ArcGIS)

Answer (score 1):

To remove a table from Table Registry you need to execute the sde command:

`sdetable -o unregister -t av.world -u av -p mo -i 7654`

This command won't remove the objectid field, so you need to do manually.

Comment: What about in the post-sde command line world? is this functionality in arc catalog now?

Comment: The command-line tools would not clean up the old-style geodatabase metadata, and the new-style (post 10) XML metadata is even less manageable from SQL.  Even if `sdetable` hadn't been unsupported for many, many moons, it would not be the correct answer here.